# Font Awesome Image Overlay

Tags: image, overlay, zurb-foundation, font-awesome

I'm currently creating a image gallery (using Zurb Foundation as Framework) and would like to show the zoom icon on image hover (like this example here: http://codepen.io/Twikito/pen/Jeaub). But I would like the icon to be a font (Font Awesome) icon and not just one but 3 individual clickable icons.. Would that be possible?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've put a [quick JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fTdRS/) together using font-awesome. The CSS is hacked together but demonstrates what's possible. It should give you a starting point to experiment with.

```
<a href="#" title="" class="image">
  <img src="http://www.lyricis.fr/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/kickass-film-still-01.jpg" alt="">
</a>

<div class="cn">
   <div class="inner">
      <a href="#zoom"><i class="icon-zoom-in large"></i></a>
      <a href="#download"><i class="icon-cloud-download large"></i></a>
      <a href="#comment"><i class="icon-comment large"></i></a>  
   </div>
</div>
```

Note: The JSfiddle above uses font-awesome.css called externally from [bootstrapcdn.com](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/)