# Center Ionic icon on top of image

Tags: css, ionic-framework, center

After reading through [Center a Font Awesome icon over the image on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27343447/center-a-font-awesome-icon-over-the-image-on-hover) and it's corresponding answers, I'm still having trouble replicating this answer with an Ionic Icon.

Code I'm using is as follows:

```
<div class="video-thumbnail">
  <img src="image here" />
  <i class="icon ion-play"></i>
</div>
```

CSS I'm using is:

```
.video-thumbnail {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.video-thumbnail img {
  position: absolute;
}

.video-thumbnail i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

I've got it to go on top of each other but can't seem to find the middle point. Looking to center horizontally and vertically. I'm not looking for any hover states just a blatant icon over image.

Thanks!

Comment: Please create a demo: http://play.ionic.io

Comment: @ManojKumar , I've created it to these specs. The images that I'll be passing in varies in size though. Thanks.

http://play.ionic.io/app/a5a36cb5b10c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For horizontal and vertical centering,

1. You need to remove `position: absolute` for the image since it takes
   it out of the flow.
2. Calculate the top and left values using `calc()`, you will need to subtract the dimension values of the icon from 50%.

```js
angular.module('app', ['ionic']);
```

```css
.video-thumbnail {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.video-thumbnail img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.video-thumbnail i {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 10px);
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
  <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <ion-pane>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Awesome App</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content class="padding">
      <div class="video-thumbnail">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT2KjQI_sGhxCm5CTyQPuCACLuLEyvup4eDNVowMzdHiiPLShdL3ggiA7QC" />
        <i class="icon ion-play"></i>
      </div>
    </ion-content>

  </ion-pane>
</body>
```

Comment: That is a fantastic solution! Thanks!